# Easy Way to Parse Hyperlinks from XML

Tags: xml, parsing

I am trying to parse an XML to spit out all the hyperlinks contained within the file. Is there an easy way to do this? It can be as simple as just outputting a file with just the links. For example:

```
<POEM>
<AUTHOR>Ogden Nash</AUTHOR>
<TITLE>Fleas</TITLE>
<LINE>Adam</LINE>
<LINE>Had 'em.</LINE>
<URL> 
<w:rStyle w:val="HyperLink"/>
<w:t>https://www.ogdennash.com/</w:t>
</w:r>
</POEM>
```

would be the XML. And I need to spit out just a text file with:

```
https://www.ogdennash.com
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What language/platform are you using for parsing? What library?

Comment: Haven't decided. That's what I'm asking for suggestions. The parsing itself is probably not going to be difficult, but is there a particular library (tree-parsing or linear parsing?) which would make this easier? I'm just figuring out DOM, SAX, etc today. I'm totally new to XML, so sorry if these are dumb questions.

As for language, I want to say Java but that's flexible too. I could do it in C but that would probably be ugly. Would Python make this easier?

I don't need specifics just some recommendations on possible approaches.

Comment: Any XML library in any language will do. Any XML parser will support XPath and allow you to extract information from XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies if you know some of this already but you say you are new to XML.

You are going to need to clean up your mark up first as its NOT strictly XML.

For example the tag

```
<w:rStyle w:val="HyperLink"/>
```

Does not have a defined namespace (w)

Also

....

```
<URL> 
    <w:rStyle w:val="HyperLink"/>
    <w:t>https://www.ogdennash.com/</w:t>
</w:r>
```

....

Is not welformed [welformed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element) xml

It should be

....

```
<URL>
    <w:r> 
        <w:rStyle w:val="HyperLink"/>
        <w:t>https://www.ogdennash.com/</w:t>
    </w:r>
</URL>
```

....

If you make the document welformed AND add a [namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace#Namespace_declaration), (i've bound w to http://foo.bar) so your xml looks like this

```
<POEM xmlns:w="http://foo.bar">
    <AUTHOR>Ogden Nash</AUTHOR>
        <TITLE>Fleas</TITLE>
        <LINE>Adam</LINE>
        <LINE>Had 'em.</LINE>
        <URL>
            <w:r>
                <w:rStyle w:val="HyperLink"/>
                <w:t>https://www.ogdennash.com/</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </URL>
</POEM>
```

Then you can use the following XPath expression

//w:t/text()

to select all the hyperlinks inside a  tag. However if you wanted to get all links inside a URL tag you would need to get the text from URL -> w:r -> w:t - the XPath for that is this

//URL/w:r/w:t/text()

If I was going to write this in Java I'd use

[JTIDY](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) to fix your markup first

Once its fixed I'd use [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) (XML Parser) and [Jaxen](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/) (XPath Library) to create the text file.

I could probably provide you a sample class that does this.

This isnt really an *easy* way to do this but it will work. I hope it gives you some pointers.

Comment: I forgot to mention that NekoHTML http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/ is very good at cleaning up markup and that you could possibly look into using that instead of JTIDY.